# Laravel 7 not all images coming from the public folder are visible

Tags: php, ubuntu, digital-ocean, laravel-7

I am using laravel 7 and my app is live and working as expected. However, one image which contains a variable, works fine locally but on my live server, even thought the url is correct in the inspection tool, is not visible on screen. I am at a loss as to how to correctly point to it. It is a static image within a folder called icons within the public folder. Here is my filesystem.php

```
'local' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app'),
        ],

        'public' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
            'url' => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

I am calling the images and files within an if statement and the images are being called just fine. They are in the public/storage/upload . Here is the code for the images and files within my show.blade.php

```
@if (in_array($extension = pathinfo($images[$i]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION), ['jpg', 'png', 'bmp']))
   <a data-toggle="" href="/storage/upload/{{ $images[$i]['name'] }}" target="_blank">
      <img src="/storage/upload/{{ $images[$i]['name'] }}" class="image-fluid w-50">
   </a>
 @else
   <a data-toggle="" href="/storage/upload/{{ $images[$i]['name'] }}" target="_blank">
      <img src="{{ "/icons/{$extension}.jpg" }}" class="image-fluid w-25">
   </a>
 @endif
```

Local host:
[image: Localhost]
Live Production Server
[image: live production site]

This works fine in local but in production, I am not sure why it is not working. I think I should mention that I am using ubuntu droplet on digitalocean. The public folder is in the document root.  If I am missing something, please let me know. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my live server, it would not look into my icons folder so I copied all my icon folder content into my img folder and changed the route from `/icons/` to `/img/` and it found the file.